# Intent Filter for Call

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

How to make my app can handle call action like this?[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your activity like so:

```
<activity android:name=".DialerActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Refer here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Phone